# Why for a linear system, the stability for a generic equlibrium point is equivalent to the stability of the origin?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am studying the concept of stability for linear and for nonlinear systems. While studying the stability for a linear system I found this definition from the notes of my professor:

> for a linear system, the stability for a generic equlibrium point is equivalent to the stability of the origin.

can somebody explain to me what does it mean?

Comment: If the equilibrium position of the linear system is stable, then any solution is stable, and vice versa. In other words, the stability of one solution implies the stability of all solutions. Consequently, linear systems are often called stable or unstable, but one can't call a nonlinear system stable or unstable because some of its solutions can be stable, while others are unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear system has the equation

$$
\dot{x} = A x
$$

and we assume that this system is stable. The equilibrium are the solution of $A x = 0$. This is a linear equation system.

Think of the points:

1. We know that a linear equation system $A x = b$  has a unique solution if and only if $A$ is nonsingular (in our case $b = 0$ but that doesn't change anything).
2. We know that all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part if and only if the linear system is stable (which is what we assumed). This means the eigenvalues are nonzero.
3. We know that a matrix $A$ can be singular if and only if it has at least one eigenvalue equal to zero.
4. We know that $x = 0$ is always a solution of $A x = 0$.

We can put it together: Because $\dot{x} = A x$ is stable the eigenvalues of $A$ are nonzero. Because the eigenvalues are nonzero, $A$ is nonsingular. Because $A$ is nonsingular $A x = 0$ has a unique solution. Because $x = 0$ is always a solution of $A x = 0$ it is always the only solution.

**Conclusion**: If $\dot{x} = A x$ is stable then its only equilibrium can be the origin.

Comment: +1, just a Note : If the matrix $A \in \mathcal{M}(n; \mathbb{R})$ is singular the null space of $A$ i.e $\mathcal{N}(A)$ defines a continuum of equilibria.