# Elementary controls question

Tags: control-theory

I'm new to differential equations as well as to controls so I'd like to show my thought process for a problem.

Let

$$
\begin{align}
\dot x &= z \\
\dot z &= -\frac{d}{dx}V_\alpha(x)
\end{align}
$$
where $V_\alpha(x) = x^4 - \alpha x^2$

We want to show that $(z,x) = (0,0)$ is an equilibrium point or all $-1 \leq \alpha \leq 1$

I started with substituting in our equation and evaluating what $\dot z$ is.

$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{d}{dx} (x^4 - \alpha x^2) &= -(4x^3 - 2\alpha x) \\
&= -2(2x^2 - \alpha x)
\end{align}
$$

I know that I'm supposed to show that at $(z,x)=(0,0)$ I'm supposed to see that when $\alpha$ is on the interval $[-1,1]$ that I have a real component but $z$ isn't in the equation...

Another aspect that I'm familiar with but still not comfortable is that I can put the equations in matrix form but this doesn't make sense to me in this context since it's just one variable.

I know I'm probably pretty far off the mark but some guidance would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For equilibrium all derivatives must be zero. So you have to find $x$, $z$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z} &= 0 \\
\dot{x} &= 0
\end{align}
$$

You have the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z} &= z \\
\dot{x} &= - \frac{d}{d x} V_{\alpha}(x)
\end{align}
$$

and $V_{\alpha}(x) = x^4 - \alpha x^2$. Your derivative is wrong, because $\frac{d}{d x} V_{\alpha}(x) = 4 x^3 - 2 \alpha x$ and so your system is

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z} &= z \\
\dot{x} &= -4 x^3 + 2 \alpha x
\end{align}
$$

First look at the first equation: You get zero derivative only when

$$
z = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Now look at the second equation: You want $-4 x^3 + 2 \alpha x = 0$. Factor out $x$ you get:

$$
x(\alpha - 2 x^2) = 0 \tag{2}
$$

This is true if $x = 0$ for all $\alpha$ so you have a equilibrium at $(z,x)=(0,0)$.

For this equilibrium the value of $\alpha$ does not matter. However you have two more equilibrium points, one at $(z,x) = (0,\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\alpha}}{2})$ and one at $(z,x) = (0,-\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\alpha}}{2})$ because there $(1)$ and $(2)$ are also zero.

Some more notes:

- You mentioned a "real component", but that is not really related to finding equilibrium points.
- You don't need $z$ in the equation because you have a second equation where $z$ appears.
- Usually you put only linear systems in matrix form. Then you can find the equilibrium points easily by solving a system of linear equations (see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633470/369884) for some more information). However your system is nonlinear so the matrix form doesn't really help.
- You don't have only one variable, you have two variables: $z$ and $x$.

Comment: I thought the derivative of $x^2$ was $2x$ so I’m not sure what happened to the 2 with the derivative of $\alpha x^2$

Comment: @financial_physician You are right, this is also wrong. I meant the step where you write $-2(2x^2 - \alpha x)$ because there you are missing the $x^3$.